# AUTO SCROLL WEB PAGE

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I auto scroll a webpage made with bootstrap? Is there any alternative to use other than jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload event, For example:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="scroll()">

<script>
function scroll() {
  // scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition)
  window.scrollTo(0, 1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```